# Upgrade your rails app from rails-4.2.5 to rails 4.2.10

Tags: ruby, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to upgrade my rails app to rails version 4.2.10 from rails version 4.2.5 . I am using react for the front end. 
What I did was:
First I remove the line gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.5' from gemfile.
Second add the line gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.10' to gemfile.
Then created a new gemset (gemset create app_name_rails_4.2.10)
gemset use app_name_rails_4.2.10.
Deleted the gemfile.lock
Then run bundle install.

After that when I start the serever ,

I am getting error in console is -----
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted `Gemfile.lock`. Instead, you should perform `bundle update rails` to update Rails to last patch.

Comment: Thanks @MarekLipka. This time I did not deleted the Gemfile.lock. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys found what I was doing wrong. Please do not delete the gemfile.lock . Instead run only bundle update rails.